# ngTable not updating after rest call

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ngTable and have a function that is called in the success block of an `$http` request:

```
$scope.setDataTable = function() {
    if($scope.tableData == undefined) return;
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        filter: {
            title: '',
            details: ''
        }
    }, {
        total: $scope.tableData.length, 
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.tableData, params.filter()) : $scope.tableData;
            var filteredDataPage = filteredData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            params.total(filteredData.length);
            $scope.tableParams.total(filteredData.total);
            return $defer.resolve(filteredDataPage);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is called in the same controller as this invocation of `$http`:

```
    $http.
        post('/rest/TheData', { 
            args : $scope.args
        }).
        success(function(data){
            $scope.tableData = data;
            $scope.setDataTable();
        }).
        error(function(data){

        });
```

This works the first time, namely when the http success is invoked the first time, the table looks correct.  However the second time, the data does not update.  What should I do here?

I've read about hacks such as

```
$scope.forceReloadTable = function(){
    $timeout($scope.setDataTable, 100)
}
```

But this did not help.